# Android: ViewPropertyAnimator pivot

Tags: android, animation

I am currently using ViewPropertyAnimators to scale an ImageView. However, the problem is that the image always scales outwards from the center, when I want it to scale from the leftmost edge and out towards the right. There does not seem to be a pivot method. Is there another way for me to do this?

Thank!

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `android:transformPivotX` and `android:transformPivotY` properties. For your specific case (left to right) something like that:

layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:transformPivotY="5dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00ffff"/>
```

java:

`v.animate().scaleX(2.0f).setDuration(1000);`

Comment: To set the pivot programmatically use:

`view.setPivotY(0f);`